# Angular bind string value in reusable checkbox component

Tags: javascript, angular

I've created a reusable checkbox component, with the purpose of selecting a single value to be added as a string, not boolean. The problem is the value is not binded in the component which uses the checkbox component, only on onChangeCategory() method. What should I do?

checkbox.html:

```
<div class="form-check" *ngFor="let cat of options">
              <input class="form-check-input"  (change)="onChangeCategory(cat, $event.target.checked)"name="{{ cat }}" type="checkbox" id="{{cat}}">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="{{cat}}">
                {{cat}}
              </label>
            </div>
```

checkbox.ts:

```
@Input() name: string;
@Input() options: string[];
@Input() selectedValue: string;

onChangeCategory(option: string, isChecked: boolean){ // Use appropriate model type instead of any
    if(isChecked) {
      this.selectedValue = option;
    }
    else {
      this.selectedValue = this.options[0];
    }

  }
```

the component using the checkbox - html:

```
<app-checkbox [options]=sexOptions
              [selectedValue]=selectedValue>
</app-checkbox>
```

the component using the checkbox - ts:

```
sexOptions: string[] = ['Male', 'Female'];
selectedValue: string; //this should take the value from the checkbox
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use 'BANANA IN A BOX' approach where your `@Input` is also `@Output`, see this [article](https://medium.com/@ofirrifo/custom-angular-component-using-two-way-data-binding-aka-banana-in-a-box-syntax-9eb06b8cfb09) for example.

HTML

```
<app-checkbox [options]=sexOptions
              [(selectedValue)]=selectedValue>
</app-checkbox>
```

TS

```
export class CheckboxComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() options: string[];
  @Input() selectedValue: string;
  @Output() selectedValueChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

  private toggle: {[key: string]: string};

  ngOnInit() {
    // I aasume we have only 2 string options
    this.toggle = {
      [this.options[0]]: this.options[1],
      [this.options[1]]: this.options[0]
    };
  }

  onChangeCategory(option: string, isChecked: boolean) {
    this.selectedValue = isChecked ? option : this.toggle[option];
    this.selectedValueChange.emit(this.selectedValue);
  }
}
```

I created a [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ujtkq7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcheckbox.component.ts) to play with. 
In my example I added a default value, if it is not required, just do not initialize it. Also I changed checks behavior to have only one single value (kind of radio options)

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I was looking for since I can bind it to my FormControl element. One more thing I want to know, is possible to bind it directly to a FormControl value (sex: FormControl ) inside a FormGroup (pacientForm: FormGroup), without explicitly assign this.pacientForm.value.sex = this.selectedValue in the parent component? Something like using @Input() group: FormGroup, @Input() controlName: string, this.selectedValueChange.emit(this.controlName)? Thanks.

Comment: I think what you need is custom angular form element (which will work as regular FormControl in both reactive and template driven forms). See example of it here: https://netbasal.com/angular-custom-form-controls-made-easy-4f963341c8e2

Comment: Actually in my case it can be much simple that that, I only need to bind the fomrControlName to the selected option, but simply applying the option from event emitter to the formControName won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check about `[@Output][1]`?

You can use it to trigger event between component and pass its values.
In your case you can do:

```
@Input() name: string;
@Input() options: string[];
@Input() selectedValue: string;

@Output() change: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter() 

onChangeCategory(option: string, isChecked: boolean){ // Use appropriate model type instead of any
  if(isChecked) {
    this.selectedValue = option;
  }
  else {
    this.selectedValue = this.options[0];
  }

  this.change.emit(this.selectedValue)
}
```

And when you use that component within the parent you want to bind the value, you do

```
<app-checkbox-component (change)="onChange($event)"></app-checkbox-component>
```

And into your parent `.ts` file

```
onChange(value) {
   console.log(value)
}
```

Comment: It works, but I want the value to be binded in a FormGroup (pacientForm: FormGroup) with a FormControl inside it (sex: new FormControl('', [])) from the parent component. If I'm using this.pacientForm.value.sex = value, on the onChange(value) method it's not binded when I'm doing the submit.